# is there a way to use a generic type alias as the generic type for a function in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

I want to be able to reuse a generic type alias as the generic type parameter for a couple of functions in Rust.

I have tried creating the following type alias following the syntax specified in the [type alias rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/type-aliases.html):

```rust
type DebuggableFromStr<T: FromStr>
where
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
= T;
```

and would like to use it to replace the generic type definitions in the following function:

```rust
fn split_string_to_vec<T: FromStr>(s: String) -> Vec<T>
where
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    s.split_whitespace()
        .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<T>>()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope since Rust doesn't enforce type bounds on type aliases. Your example is equivalent to this:

```
type DebuggableFromStr<T> = T;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd0b2c3fe7a9501c63232901672dc3c4).

I don't believe it to be specifically documented anywhere but the compiler issues a warning if you try.